# Django & Postgresql & South: convert CharField to DecimalField

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I've changed a CharField to DecimalField and got this error from South:

HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion

So I googled it and used this:

> ```
>     db.execute(
>         'ALTER TABLE "user_profile" '
>         'ALTER COLUMN "proxy_score" DROP DEFAULT, '
>         'ALTER COLUMN "proxy_score" DROP NOT NULL, '
>         'ALTER COLUMN "proxy_score" TYPE NUMERIC USING to_number("proxy_score", "99.99")'
>     )
> ```
>
> this is the error I'm getting after running my migration code through south: django.db.utils.DatabaseError: column "99.99" does not exist

but something is wrong with my to_number.

What am i missing?

I would like to support 4 digits decimal number for example: 12.35

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try without the double quotes around `99.99`.

```
ALTER TABLE user_profile
ALTER COLUMN proxy_score TYPE NUMERIC USING to_number(proxy_score, '99.99');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e7a17/1